# Why wordpress is hitting another url

Tags: hacked

I got a mail from main hosting that your wordpress site is attacking or hitting another website each and everytime it loaded. I have checked all the plugins and code but couldn't find any solution.I dont know why i am getting this issue.If anyone is familiar please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess that there is some rogue code on your site. (Assumption, since I don't know your site URL.)

You'll need to check everything: update (from known good source) everything (WP, themes, plugins), then look at each folder for a file that doesn't have the current date (since you just updated everything).

Change the credentials on everything: WP admin users, hosting, FTP, etc.

Remove any plugins/themes that you are not using.

Look at the generated page code and see if you find anything that doesn't belong after you have fixed/updated every.

I've developed a process to clean up a hacked site - see here: https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/